# How would I write this C function in Rust?

Tags: pointers, rust

How would I write the function below in Rust? Is there a way to write `replace()` safely or is the operation inherently unsafe? `list` does not have to be an array, a vector would work as well. It's the replacement operation that I'm interested in.

```c
void replace(int *list[], int a, int b) {
    *list[a] = *list[b];
}
```

I would like the following behavior:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int *list[] = { &a, &a, &b, &b };

*list[0] = 3;        // list has pointers to values: [3, 3, 2, 2]
replace(list, 2, 0); // list has pointers to values: [3, 3, 3, 3]
*list[0] = 4;        // list has pointers to values: [4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: @Deduplicator Sorry, that's reasonable.

Comment: @Shepmaster I have updated the description with the desired behavior.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. *Why* do you want to have multiple mutable references to the same variable? Doing so is straight-up not allowed in Rust, but maybe the problem you are trying to solve with mutable aliases *is* solvable in Rust, if we look at the problem in a different way.

Comment: @Shepmaster Say I have a type like HashMap<int, **HashSet<int>>, I wish to enforce a property of this structure so that each map key contains a reference to the set to which the key belongs. Now, I wish to implement a Merge function that will merge two of the sets. But I want this to update all the keys of both sets to point to the new merged one.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but "each map key contains a reference to the set" - isn't that what a HashMap *does*? Keeps a relation between the key and the value?

Comment: @Shepmaster The idea is that given a member of one of the sets, I can quickly determine which set it belongs to and the size of the set. If I merge sets, I will have to update the keys to point to the new set. Using a double pointer analog will allow me to do this immediately.

Comment: @Shepmaster Well I figured it out creating a kind of virtual heap with another array.Anyways I'll pick your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer for modified question

Rust [does not allow](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/pointers.html#references) you to have multiple mutable references (*aliasing*) to the same item. This means you'd never be able to run the equivalent of your third line:

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = 1;
    let vals = &[&mut a, &mut a];
}
```

This fails with:

```
cannot borrow `a` as mutable more than once at a time
```

> What about using Rc and RefCell?

[`Rc`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) doesn't let us mutate the value:

> A reference-counted pointer type over an **immutable value**.

(Emphasis mine)

[`RefCell::borrow_mut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut) won't allow multiple concurrent borrows:

> Panics if the value is currently borrowed.

#### Answer for original question

It's basically the same. I picked a `u8` cause it's easier to type. :-)

```
fn replace(v: &mut [&mut u8], a: usize, b: usize) {
    *v[a] = *v[b]
}

fn main() {
    let mut vals = vec![1,2,3,4];
    {
        let mut val_refs: Vec<&mut u8> = vals.iter_mut().collect();
        replace(&mut val_refs, 0, 3);
    }
    println!("{:?}", vals);
}
```

([playpen link](http://is.gd/iDnIzh))

Rust does do boundary-checking, so if you call with an index bigger than the slice, the program will panic and you don't get memory corruption.

Comment: I don't think it would work with this:
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int *list[] = { &a, &a, &b, &b };

Comment: What about using Rc and RefCell?

Comment: Ok, so the operation is inherently unsafe.